# loop thru divs in jsp

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

I tried searching on how to do this but was not able to get the thing that I need. I have a database and I would like a div display its content. I was able to show it through a table and have it on for each like this.

```
<c:forEach items="${listArtists}" var="artist">
            <tr>
            <td style= "height: 300px; width: 200px"> <img style="height: 100%; width:100%" src="/img/artistphotos/${artist.photo}" alt="" /> </td>
                <td>${artist.artistName}</td>
                <td>${artist.age}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

now I want to display the following data in this div, that instead of creating another row in a table, it would create another div with the next using this format.

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="/img/artistphotos/${artist.photo}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="portfolio-caption">
                    <h4>${artist.artistName}</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">${artist.age}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

hoping for help and guidance. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply take the same loop and replace the `tr` with your `div`?

```
<c:forEach items="${listArtists}" var="artist">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
        <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
            <div class="portfolio-hover">
                <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="/img/artistphotos/${artist.photo}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="portfolio-caption">
            <h4>${artist.artistName}</h4>
            <p class="text-muted">${artist.age}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: you are correct. the only thing that im missing is that i forgot to add my library of jstl at the beginning of my jsp.
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

Comment: What is listArtists here, is it servlet session attribute name?